# Set Revmob banner frame for iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, frame, revmob

I am using Revmob for showing add banner using below code.

> [RevMobAds startSessionWithAppID:@"My Application id"];
>
> [RevMobAds session].testingMode = RevMobAdsTestingModeWithAds;
>
> [[RevMobAds session] showBanner];

and it's showing test banner perfectly at the bottom.

Now my question is i want to set this banner at the top of my application.

so how can i set this banner frame ?

I have tried to use RevMobBannerView

My code is

> RevMobBannerView *banner = [[RevMobBannerView alloc]
> initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 50)];
>
> ```
> [banner setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
>
> [banner loadAd];
>
> [self.window addSubview:banner];
> ```

but it's not working...it's not showing anything into screen.

any help will be apriciated...

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case tkanzakic answer didn't work, you can always use a UIView to put the banner into and add it to your view. In banner load delegate, resize your intermediate view to banner's bounds.

**edit:**
Something like

```
ad = [[[RevMobAds session] bannerView] retain];
ad.delegate = self;
[ad loadAd];

- (void)revmobAdDidReceive {
  intermediateView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, somewidth, someheight);
  ad.frame = intermediateView.bounds;
  [intermediateView addSubview:ad];
}
```

Comment: @ Luis..i have tried to do as you say...but not able to add bannerview as subview of UIView..Can you post some code ?

Comment: Thanks Luis, I had Soved this issue tomorrow by using same solution that you posted..yes it's working. +1 for you...and Thanks again for help.

Comment: Hello Luis Can you help me in my Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452416/revmob-check-banner-is-loaded-or-not-in-iphone

Answer (score 4):

From [RevMob Documentation site](http://sdk.revmob.com/ios-api/Classes/RevMobAds.html#//api/name/bannerView):

```
RevMobBannerView *ad = [[RevMobAds session] bannerView];
ad.delegate = self;
[ad loadAd];
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
  ad.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 114);
} else {
  ad.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50);
}

[self.view addSubView:ad];
```

Answer (score 1):

the `RevMobAds` object has a `RevMobBannerView` property, and this property has a `frame`. Accordingly to the [documentation](http://sdk.revmob.com/ios-api/Classes/RevMobBanner.html#//api/name/frame):

> You can use this property to define the position of the banner in the screen. The default is a banner on the botton of the screen

**EDIT:**

Try this to set the frame:

```
RevMobAds *revMovAds = [RevMobAds startSessionWithAppID:@"My Application id"];
revMovAds.bannerView.frame = CGRect(x,y,xx,yy);
[revMovAds showBanner];
```

Comment: @tkanzakic...Thanks for the Quick reply..Actually i have tried this but not working for me..for that i am using code like...see the Edited Question...

Comment: I edit my answer adding some code, I'm not in my development PC and I can not test it now, sorry

Comment: i have tried your code but it's not working...and edited your code as i tried

Comment: @ tkanzakic..Thanks for the help, we have to use code as Luis suggest...+1 for you help.

Answer (score 0):

When I'm adding it(RevMob version 5.9) in my project. I do it like this:

```
[RevMobAds startSessionWithAppID:@"my id"];
RevMobBannerView *ad = [[RevMobAds session] bannerView]; // you must retain this object
[ad loadWithSuccessHandler:^(RevMobBannerView *banner) {
    banner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 381, 320, 50);
    [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:banner];
    NSLog(@"Ad loaded");
} andLoadFailHandler:^(RevMobBannerView *banner, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Ad error: %@",error);
} onClickHandler:^(RevMobBannerView *banner) {
    NSLog(@"Ad clicked");
}];
```