# RevMob check Banner is loaded or not in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, frame, banner, revmob

I am using Revmob Framework for displaying ad banners and it's working fine.

So now my Question is that how to know programmatically that banner is loaded or not?

Like if we are using iads then there is a method "isBannerLoaded" to check banner is loaded or not.

Actually I want to set it's frame as banner is loaded or not loaded.

So is there any method like "isBannerLoaded" in Revmob Framework?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the revMobDelegate and use revmobAdDidReceive:

```
@interface MyAdClass : NSObject <RevMobAdsDelegate>
...

@implementation MyAdClass
-(void) prepare {
    ...
    ad = [[[RevMobAds session] bannerView] retain];
    ad.delegate = self;
    [ad loadAd];
    ...
} 

- (void)revmobAdDidReceive {
    NSLog(@"ad received");
    ...
}
```

You can find RevMobAdsDelegate documentation at http://sdk.revmob.com/ios-api/Protocols/RevMobAdsDelegate.html

Comment: Hey Luis i know all Delegate methods and i am using this one right now..and this method calls when ad received. but i want to know like if you ever used iAds then there is also a delegate method and other method "isBannerLoaded". by calling this method you got banner status, loaded or not. ??

Comment: and currently i am using custom solution...that took one flag for banner.and set it in delegate methods that ad received or fail.

Comment: This method is all you have so you need to use a flag, like you already do. Though somewhat similars, Api for iad and Revmob are a bit different.